# React Link to function isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I can't seem to solve this or find an answer. I have a basic React Router setup that I'm trying to get working and I'm really stuck on getting the Link to function to work.

Thanks in advance.

Wireframe Example

Here's the code.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import reactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import About from "./About Us/About"
import FrontPage from "./Front Page/FrontPage"
import HeaderNavigation from './General/HeaderNavigation';


reactDOM.render((
    <Router history = {hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={FrontPage}>
            <IndexRoute component = {HeaderNavigation}/>
            <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

HeaderNavigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem, Link } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default React.createClass ({
    render() {
        var Dlink = 'https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12373357_497613000418878_5796459715901767943_n.png?oh=0484e476279b076d27eeeadc2d12b1d8&oe=590CD405'
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <img src= {Dlink} alt="Legalink" height="6000 px"/>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>
                        <Nav bsStyle = "pills">
                            <NavItem eventKey = "{1}" disabled>Product</NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey = "{2}">
                                <Link to ="/About">About</Link>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavDropdown title  ="More" eventKey = "{3}">
                                <MenuItem eventKey = "{1}">Background</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem eventKey = "{2}">Contact Us</MenuItem>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                </Navbar>
        {this.props.children},
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

About.js

```
    import React from "react";

/* Styles */
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';


export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Legalink</h2>
                            <p>Our vision is to change the way Law firms engage with work and prove there worth</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Tiger Jockey's</h2>
                            <p>Our Tiger Jockey's are C-suite level professionals who know what it takes to stay on the ride</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Based in Melbourne Australia and founded by a mixture of Lawyers and Engineer's</h2>
                            <p>The right team to bring you the right product</p>
                            <p><Button>View details</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

FrontPage.js

```
/**
 * Created by Hewlbern on 30-Jan-17.
 */
import React from 'react';

import Carousel from './Carousel';
import Body from './Body';
import Footer from './Footer';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>

            <Carousel/>,
            <Body/>,
            <Footer/>,
        </div>
    }
})
```

Body.js

```
import React from "react";

/* Styles */
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import typography from "../Assets/Typography"

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <Grid className = {typography}>
                        <h1>Tiger Jockey</h1>
                        <p>Bringing M&A to the Agile century</p>
                    </Grid>
                </Jumbotron>

                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2 className = {typography}>Ride the Tiger</h2>
                            <p>Be the Jockey.</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Please your Customer</h2>
                            <p>Win more work</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Improve your process</h2>
                            <p>Make more money</p>
                            <p><Button>View details</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The error I'm getting is

```
"Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `HeaderNavigation`.
printWarning @ warning.js:36
invariant.js:51Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `HeaderNavigation`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:68)
    at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
    at ReactChildReconciler.js:71
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:93)
    at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
    at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:187)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:226)
ReactDOMComponentTree.js:106Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$gz5475fv0m1hbexy0fg6kzkt9' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (ReactDOMComponentTree.js:106)
    at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:38)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:67)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:140)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:147)"
```

Comment: I don't see the files you've listed (App.js, HeaderNavigation.js, or About.js) mentioned anywhere in the Error. Are there any familiar file names mentioned in the Error you can add to your question?

Comment: Definitely although I don't think they are necessarily related as the error seems to only occur when i ad the Link to function

Comment: @RyanBach Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Link`, as you're using it comes from `react-router`, not `react-bootstrap`.

You should be able to fix it by changing:

`import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem, Link } from 'react-bootstrap';`

to:

`import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad that I could help!